# How to create a recording bot for MS teams?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm developing a MS Teams bot.
My requirements are that , bot should join a specific call and record the audio and I need to access that audio file.
I'm referring to recording bots sample provided by Microsoft https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/AksSamples/teams-recording-bot but not able to configure it using the steps provided.

Comment: Have you tried following the steps provided in this sample tutorial? What part are you stuck on?

Comment: Ya, I want to set up the bot on my local machine , I have installed ngrok and using pro subscription of that as mentioned. Now I'm not clear how to proceed futher , can you provide detailed steps to set up the bot on my local machine?

Comment: Here is document for deploy bot-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-create-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&viewFallbackFrom=azure-bot-service-3.0&tabs=csharp%2Cvs

Comment: While running the code I'm getting this error-

1. Error CS0006 Metadata file 'C:\Users\rksha\Downloads\microsoft-graph-comms-samples-master\microsoft-graph-comms-samples-master\Samples\V1.0Samples\AksSamples\teams-recording-bot\src\RecordingBot.Services\bin\x64\Debug\net472\RecordingBot.Services.dll' could not be found RecordingBot.Console

Comment: 2nd Error is ------
Error MSB3491 Could not write lines to file "obj\x64\Debug\net472\RecordingBot.Services.GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig". Path: obj\x64\Debug\net472\RecordingBot.Services.GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig exceeds the OS max path limit. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters.

Comment: Looks like your path is too long, can you please check on it and try once.

Comment: Move the folder for that sample closer to the root directory, say at `C:\Users\rksha` and try again.

Comment: Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved or still looking for any help?